# '[AnyObject]?' is not convertible to 'NSArray'(xcode,swift)

Tags: ios, swift

The error is in `let USER:PFUser`...  It was working good but when I updated Xcode this problem appeared. The name of the username is not being displayed.

```
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postcells: postsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postsTableViewCell

    let Post:PFObject = self.PostData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


    postcells.postTimetextView.text = Post.objectForKey("Content") as! String


    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    postcells.timeStamp.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(Post.createdAt!)


    var findPostedBy:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    findPostedBy.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: Post.objectForKey("Postedby")!)

    findPostedBy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let USER:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
                postcells.usernameLabel3.text = USER.username



            }
        }

    return postcells
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that an array was returned from parse

You can use this:

```
findPostedBy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if objects?.count > 0 {

                let USER:PFUser = objects!.last as! PFUser

            // Avoid updating the UI on a background thread

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                postcells.usernameLabel3.text = USER.username
            })
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont know why my username is not being displayed

Comment: it have been saved in parse but not showing the data @thefredelement

Comment: Is this error: '[AnyObject]?' is not convertible to 'NSArray'(xcode,swift) - gone?

Comment: Updated my answer, if the data exists you just dispatch UI updates to the main queue.

Comment: Its a very different problem.The values are storing in parse but in xcode its showing the values null. I think my coding for finding the values from parse is wrong.Should i post all code ?

Comment: You need to make sure that you have access to the that information. The PFUser class is restricted by default. On Stack Overflow it's a good idea to have one problem for one question so it can help people in the future. If your original problem is solved you should research your new problem and mark this answer as correct so someone in the future will know that it works.